# What is wrong with my java code for Project Euler's program 4? (finding the largest palindrome of 2 3 digit numbers)

Tags: java, algorithm, palindrome

> This is my code and the answer always seems to 100001 (its not even
>   performing the loop). 
>       I know there are much easier ways to solve this problem but what exactly is wrong with this particular code? and how do I fix it?

```
public class LargestPalindromes
{

 public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int largest = 100001;

    for(int i = 100; i < 1000; i++)
    {           
        for(int j = 100; j < 1000; j++)
        {
            int mult = i * j;
            if(largest < mult && isPalindrome(mult))
                largest = mult;
        }
    }

    System.out.printf("\n\nThe largest palindrome is: %d\n\n", largest);
}

public static boolean isPalindrome(int mult)
{
    int n1=0, n2=0, n3=0, n4=0, n5=0, n6=0;
    int largest = 0, count = 0, p =100000;
    int x = mult;

    while(count < 6)
    {
        if(count == 1)
            n1 = x / p;
        else if(count == 2)
            n2 = x / p;
        else if(count == 3)
            n3 = x / p;
        else if(count == 4)
            n4 = x / p;
        else if(count == 5)
            n5 = x / p;
        else if(count == 6)
            n6 = x / p;

        x %= p;

        p /= 10;

        count++;
    }   

    int reverse = Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(n1) + String.valueOf(n2) + String.valueOf(n3) + String.valueOf(n4) + String.valueOf(n5) + String.valueOf(n6));

    return reverse == mult; 
}
}
```

Comment: Explain the expected output with corresponding input if any!

Comment: The result is supposed to be 906609 wich is the largest palindrome formed by multiplication of two triple digit numbers but my result is always 100001. There are no inputs from my end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were too many errors in your original `public static boolean isPalindrome(int mult)` method. So I replaced it with the standard version:

```
public static boolean isPalindrome(int mult)
{

   int temp=mult;    
   int r,sum=0; 
   while(mult>0){    
     r=mult%10;  //getting remainder  
     sum=(sum*10)+r;    
     mult=mult/10;    
  }    
  if(temp==sum)    
      return true;
  else{
      return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: That `if/else` construct at the end can be replaced with `return temp == sum;`

Comment: @Blastfurnace So that means this answer deserves a downvote?

Comment: @VidorVistrom Thank you for your answer...it worked well

Comment: @BlacburnResnov Accept it then